# ASP.NET MVC app when I click on a link the page is blank, then refresh and it shows properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC application with two cshtml files.  When I move from one to the other, i get a blank page, but when i refresh it shows properly.  Using jQuery, jQueryMobile.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  Turns out that ASP.NeT MVC was adding bootstrap and that and jqueryMobile  were fighting it out.  By removing the Bootstrap and/or the layout page, the problem went away.